# How can I capture an escaped " but not an unescaped one?

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose the portion that needs to be captured by regex is indicated by PORTION in the following string

```
,"PORTION","","a",["some_string"]
```

Examples of PORTION are

- \"abc123
- abc123\"
- \"abc123\"
- abc\"123\"
- abc123

so the strings actually look like

- ,"\"abc123","","a",["some_string"]
- ,"abc123\" ","","a",["some_string"]
- "\"abc123\"","","a",["some_string"]
- "abc\"123\"","","a",["some_string"]
- "abc123","","a",["some_string"]

PORTION is surrounded by double quotes. Double quotes inside PORTION are escaped by backslash. My current pattern is

```
my $pattern = '(.?([\\"]|[^"][^,][^"])*)';
```

which produces the results for the above examples as follows

- \"abc123","","a"
- abc123
- \"abc12
- abc\"123\""
- abc123"

The pattern tries to match everything in front of a sequence that is not ","
and also allow the capturing of \"
But it's not working as intended.
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 5):

You're making it way too complicated; there's no rule that says you have to do all your parsing in one monolithic regex. Since your string looks like a comma-delimited sequence, first parse it as such:

```
my @fields = split /(?<!\\),/, $string;   # use comma as a delimiter (except when escaped)
```

...And then parse your first field accordingly:

```
shift @fields unless $fields[0];     # pull off the potentially null first field
$fields[0] =~ s/^"//g;               # remove the leading "
$fields[0] =~ s/(?<!\\)"$//g;        # remove the trailing " that isn't preceded by a \
```

You could parse all your fields this way by wrapping the above code in a for loop or map().

Note that this code does not account for such occurrences such as `\\,` (the comma is a valid delimiter here, even though it will pass through the regex incorrectly). Therefore, it would be much preferred to use a proper parser for your format (whatever it is). You may want to take a look at [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV).

Comment: That will break if one of the fields contains a comma. It may be safe to assume that's true, but also may not.

Comment: @eaolson: the OP doesn't specify whether that would be valid. As I noted, the complications of parsing escape characters necessitates a more sophisticated parser than simple regexes can provide. One would need to start at the beginning of the string and interpret each character individually. Consider a long sequence of backslaxhes followed by a semicolon - is it escaped or not? One would have to start counting at the beginning of the sequence to know.

Comment: Using a CSV parser will take into account quotes.

Comment: +1 for the gentle reminder that not all parsing needs to be done in one monolithic regex

Comment: when I said "semicolon" in my comment above I meant "double quote" :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3aCSV)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem calls for the infamous **zero-width negative look-behind assertion**

...which lets you match a `foo` that *doesn't* follow a `bar`.

The doc is here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns

and you want something like this in your regexp:

```
"(.+?)(?<!\\)"
```

that matches a double quote, as few as possible of any char(s), then another double quote not preceded by a backslash (escaped by doubling, I think). The first set of parens captures as you intend, the second parentheses are not capturing.

**Edit:** Meanwhile tested using http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/regex-tester/
and it seems to work fine.

**Edit:** As outis points out, this expression will not correctly match a PORTION in which the final character before the closing quote is an escaped backslash. If you don't anticipate backslashes in your text you should be fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to allow for escaped backslashes along with escaped quotes. Using REs to matched balanced anything gets ugly fast:

```
/(?<=")((?:[^"\\]+|\\+[^"\\]|(?:\\\\)+|(?<!\\)\\(?:\\\\)*")*)(?=")/
```

Do yourself a favor and use a parser, as Ether suggests.

Comment: Escaped backslashes aren't that hard to deal with: `(?>[^"\\]+|\\.)*`.  You could also write it as `(?>[^"\\]+|\\["\\])*`, but the dot doesn't cause any problems, and it takes care of any other backslash-escape sequence you might want to support.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is comma delimited and do not have embedded commas, just split on "," and get the appropriate fields

```
while(<>){
    chomp;
    @s = split /,/;
    if ($s[0] eq ""){
        print "$s[1]\n";
    }else{
        print $s[0]."\n";
    }
}
```

output

```
$ perl perl.pl file
"\"abc123"
"abc123\" "
"\"abc123\""
"abc\"123\""
"abc123"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to consider escaped backslashes as mentioned by outis, you can use this:

```
m/"((\\\\|\\"|[^"])+)"/
```

(It seems I can not leave comment on outis' answer, but outis solution does not work with this:

```
"abc\\\"123"
```

will produce

```
abc\\\
```

)

Input:

```
,"\"abc123","","a",["some_string"]
,"abc123\" ","","a",["some_string"]
"\"abc123\"","","a",["some_string"]
"abc\"123\"","","a",["some_string"]
"abc123","","a",["some_string"]
"ab\\c123","","a",["some_string"]
"abc123\\","","a",["some_string"]
"abc123\\\"","","a",["some_string"]
"abc\\\"123\"","","a",["some_string"]
"abc123\\\\\"","","a",["some_string"]
```

Output:

```
\"abc123
abc123\" 
\"abc123\"
abc\"123\"
abc123
ab\\c123
abc123\\
abc123\\\"
abc\\\"123\"
abc123\\\\\"
```